# Google Chart getImageUri for Gauge chart

Tags: google-visualization, google-gauges

In our application we are creating lots of charts using google charts and we need to create image from those charts. For core charts we are able to generate the images using getImageUri, but for gauge charts it is not supported. How can we achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can try using [html2canvas](https://html2canvas.hertzen.com) library:

```
     $('#load').click(function(){

        html2canvas($('#chartdiv'), {
            onrendered: function (canvas) {
                var img = canvas.toDataURL("image/png")
                window.open(img);
            }
        });

});
```